# How do I print content from a select via node.js in html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    });
    res.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    res.write("<html>");
    res.write("<head>");
    res.write("<title>Pagina Node.js!</title>");
    res.write("</head>");
    res.write("<body>");
    res.write("<p>Sono un paragrafo <strong>HTML</strong>!</p>");
    res.write("<br>");
    //         res.write(prova);
    res.write("</body>");
    res.write("</html>");

    res.end();
});

server.listen(8080);

console.log("Server is listening");

//app.js

var mysql = require('mysql');

var prova = "";

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "giocodiimmagini"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    prova = con.query("SELECT i.imgDir FROM image i", function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);

        con.query(prova, (err, res, cols) => {

            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(res);

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: You have to move your code around for that. In the function you pass to `createServer`, first call your `con.query()`. in the `(err, res, cols)` callback, send back the HTML. Note that you should change `res` to `resDB` or something, otherwise it's going to shadow the `res` you use to write the reply. - - In the long run you should use [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) though to create a node-based web server.

Comment: sorry, i don't' understand; can you show how the code would be written please?

Comment: This is the basic idea: https://pastebin.com/tjtUwXCZ - - If you don't want to go down into what's known as [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), try using `async/await` instead and you can split this into functions.

Comment: Ok it works, thanks a lot, now that I've done this exercise I have to try to understand why to write with this language instead of php :) https://pastebin.com/DL50VcBw

Comment: Yeah, it can be weird to use JS on the server side, but it's so much better than PHP once you get used to it :)